# Invalid SplitApkBundle. The bundle targets unknown languages: [gr]. google play console

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

Android app bundle upload failed with error

**`Invalid SplitApkBundle. The bundle targets unknown languages: [gr]`**

[image]

Android Studio version 3.5

**I tried**

1. Clean & rebuild
2. Invalidate cache/restart

Comment: I just ran into the same issue. Might be Google Play related.

Comment: Same thing is happening to me since 15 mins ago, buy it says "[cb]" instead. I'm also using AS 3.5, but over the few past days I could upload the bundle without any trouble, so it must be something with google play as @RubenAalders says

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had the same issue.
**Invalid SplitApkBundle. The bundle targets unknown languages:[cb]**

I solved by setting DSL to stop aapt package building the wrong language targets.

My app supports English and Chinese, therefore resConfigs only needs en and zh.

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    resConfigs "en", "zh-rTW", "zh-rCN"
}
```

Comment: This did help, but why does google assume the other languages when I don't define any?

Comment: It help me. Thanks

Comment: @SEG.Veenstra - Probably due to a plugin/library that you use.  It's irritating, and difficult to find/remove.

Comment: I had the same issue with language 'web'! Adding the app supported languages in resConfigs  solved the problem.

Answer (score 20):

Apply this to Android{}

```
bundle {
    density {
        // Different APKs are generated for devices with different screen densities; true by default.
        enableSplit true
    }
    abi {
        // Different APKs are generated for devices with different CPU architectures; true by default.
        enableSplit true
    }
    language {
        // This is disabled so that the App Bundle does NOT split the APK for each language.
        // We're gonna use the same APK for all languages.
        enableSplit false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in my case i was because i was using facebook account kit see wells answer it helped me out , i am in lining it here for future references

```
bundle {
    density {
        // Different APKs are generated for devices with different screen densities; true by default.
        enableSplit true
    }
    abi {
        // Different APKs are generated for devices with different CPU architectures; true by default.
        enableSplit true
    }
    language {
        // This is disabled so that the App Bundle does NOT split the APK for each language.
        // We're gonna use the same APK for all languages.
        enableSplit false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue after downgrading facebook login implimentation to 5.8 it's fixed

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.8.0'
```

Comment: Downgrading facebook-login from 5.11.0 to 5.8.0 fixes.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was working with **Localization and Translation** also. It worked. no more code.

Put this code in app-level build.gradle.

```
android {
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issue, I guess it is related to some resources added for **Facebook's Account Kit** *(specifically the values inside /res/values-cb/values-cb.xml)* I've tried uploading a version without this SDK and the playstore proccessed it properly

Comment: I never used Facebook sdk

Comment: @FarhanAli What did you do, I use the FB Account Kit and still need to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Switching to Facebook sdk version 5.13.0 solved the problem for me.

```groovy
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.13.0'
```