# Invalid splitapkbundle. The bundle target unknown language: [gr]

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, google-play-console

Upload app bundle failed.

After I change version of dependencies

```
> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
```

3.4.1 to 3.5.0

I'm getting this error.

I solve by this method but it is true or false I don't know see below

```
> bundle {
>     density {
>         // Different APKs are generated for devices with different screen densities; true by default.
>         enableSplit true
>     }
>     abi {
>         // Different APKs are generated for devices with different CPU architectures; true by default.
>         enableSplit true
>     }
>     language {
>         // This is disabled so that the App Bundle does NOT split the APK for each language.
>         // We're gonna use the same APK for all languages.
>         enableSplit false
>     } }
```

[image]

Comment: I have a same problem, is any one find answer?

Comment: try this defaultConfig {
 
    resConfigs "en"
} en for english language

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid SplitApkBundle. The bundle targets unknown languages: \[gr\]. google play console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57859122/invalid-splitapkbundle-the-bundle-targets-unknown-languages-gr-google-play)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are two methods

---

> **1) first methods**

---

I solve this issue by using this method but it is only for the English language

**Invalid SplitApkBundle. The bundle targets unknown languages:[gr].**

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    resConfigs "en" }
```

---

> **2) second method**

---

```
bundle {
    density {
        // Different APKs are generated for devices with different screen densities; true by default.
        enableSplit true
    }
    abi {
        // Different APKs are generated for devices with different CPU architectures; true by default.
        enableSplit true
    }
    language {
        // This is disabled so that the App Bundle does NOT split the APK for each language.
        // We're gonna use the same APK for all languages.
        enableSplit false
    }
}
```