# How to fix 'Invalid SplitApkBundle' failure

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-console

I have run application to test without any problem but when I tried to upload App Bundle to Google Play Console it failed with this message:

> Invalid SplitApkBundle. The bundle targets unknown languages: [cb].

I have tried several times but nothing changes. It did not happen before, and I have changed just version informations on gradle files.

Comment: checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57859122/invalid-splitapkbundle-the-bundle-targets-unknown-languages-gr-google-play

Comment: I found a solution there, but still don't know why this problem occured. Thanks!