# Getting error while uploading android app bundle to playstore.. Your app bundle targets unrecognized language jp

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have created signed android app bundle and while uploading it on playstore. I am getting the following error:

> Your app bundle targets the following unrecognized languages: jp. The list of supported language codes can be found in the IANA registry. Invalid languages caused by third-party libraries can be excluded using the resConfigs Gradle property. You need to use a different package name beacuse "com.example" is restricted.

I have used resConfigs gradle propoerty in defaultConfig too. I have also changed the package name.

But still getting this error.

I have used ads and firebase dependencies in the project and some third party libraries too.

[image: error coming]

[image: code desc]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid SplitApkBundle. The bundle targets unknown languages: \[gr\]. google play console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57859122/invalid-splitapkbundle-the-bundle-targets-unknown-languages-gr-google-play)

Comment: I checked it earlier.. But unfortunately, its not related :(

Comment: are you using Japanese (Japan) language in your code? or if you are using some library which may include Japanese language support?

Comment: I think the taggroup dependency uses japanese language.. What should I do for it? I have used resConfigs ja_rJP as well..

Comment: `resConfigs` should suffice. Are you sure you're uploading what you've compiled? The package name seems to be different...

Answer (score 0):

If you are not supporting Japanese language, than you should not mention in resConfigs. You should only include languages name inside resConfigs which are supported by your app only.

If you are supprting Japanese langauge than code for japanese language is ja or ja_JP (not ja_rJP).

For supporting list of multiple languages, you can check [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android)

Edit:

You said you only used "en", than in gradle why you are using `resConfigs "en", "zh-rTW", "zh-rCN", "ja_rJP.`

Remove this line and just add `resConfigs "en"`.

Comment: I haven't used japanese language in my app but still its giving this error may be because of some library

Comment: as you have used ja_rJP  in resConfigs, you have to change it to ja_JP.

Comment: If you are only supporting english language than use only resConfigs "en".

Comment: Ok let me do it again but I used "en" only.. Still getting same error

Comment: Strange, because I did same thing and it worked for me before some months ago. Can you show your code where you have place this code and also check resConfigs  is inside your App Level gradle (Sometime by mistake we can add to other library's app level gradle)

Comment: ok I am attaching the code picture.. But I am using this library [link] (https://github.com/2dxgujun/AndroidTagGroup).. Is there any problem with this library?? What do u think??